# Is it possible to intercept and modify a wireless TCP transmission?

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, tcp

Given three parties (all in the same LAN): A client, a server, and a MITM. The client and server communicate wirelessly, and don't encrypt their messages. The MITM can see the messages, but question is: could he modify the packets sent from the client?

The wireless network is not owned by the MITM, but he can see the packets since his network adapter supports monitor mode.

Comment: Yes he can modify packets.

Comment: Look up ARP spoofing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways. One of them is ARP spoofing. In it, the MITM can link their MAC address with the IP address of a legitimate computer or server on the network. Then, any messages to the intended IP address will be sent to the attacker.

Visit https://www.veracode.com/security/arp-spoofing to learn more about ARP spoofing.

More examples of it would be:

- DNS Spoofing
- mDNS Spoofing
  Read this to learn more: https://www.rapid7.com/fundamentals/man-in-the-middle-attacks/